# Order of dates is not chronological in ggplot2

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a graph to depict a population over a period of time. However, the dates are not in chronological order. In the imported CSV the dates are all correct and in order. However, once the code below is run, the graph presented does not have the dates in the correct order. The starting date is in the middle and the ending date is on the left of the starting date. Is there any way I can fix it?

```
sumc <- aggregate(ex2$C, bu=list(ex2$Date, ex2$Temp), FUN=sum)
colnames(sumc) <- c("Date", "Temperature", "Individuals")
ggplot(data= sumc, aes(x=Date, y=Individuals, group=Temperature, colour=Temperature )) + geom_line() + theme(plot.title = element_text(face="bold") 
    ,plot.background = element_blank()
    ,panel.background = element_blank()
    ,panel.grid.major = element_blank()
    ,panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
    ,panel.border = element_blank()
    ,axis.line = element_line(colour="black", size=1)
    ,axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black", size=10)
    ,axis.text.y = element_text(color="black", size=8)
    ,axis.title.x = element_text(colour="black", size=10, face="bold", vjust=-.2)
    ,axis.title.y = element_text(color="black", size=10, face="bold", vjust=1.2)
    ,legend.text=element_text(size=8))
```

This image is the population over time. But as you can see the dates on the x axis are incorrect and off:

[image: This image is the population over time. But as you can see the dates on the x-axis are incorrect and off.]

Comment: *Details* would help ... what **is** the order?  One thing that immediately pops into my mind is that perhaps the system is perceiving the data-type of the axis to be, say, "string," not "date." Could the ordering that you're seeing be somehow consistent with such a (mis-)interpretation?

Comment: The order is from the starting date of 7/5/2016 and so on until the ending date of 7/20/2016. I've used this code successfully on another graph and it has come up correct. I'm not sure if it could be a misinterpretation due to that error because it was successful on another graph.

Comment: But I observe that the ordering *is consistent(!)* with my hypothesis that the date-strings are being interpreted as *character strings,* not *dates.* We therefore must not exclude the possibility that the success of your "other graph" was merely fortuitous . . . that you saw nothing in that particular output to reveal the *bug(!)* to you.

Comment: The problem is that your data is not of class `Date`, it is just, as Mike says, being used as a string. If you convert to `Date` class everything will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dates are imported in the correct order in the data frame, use

`sumc$Date <- factor(sumc$Date, ordered = T)`

prior to plotting. This will make them as ordered factors based on the order they appear, and ggplot will understand that it has to keep them that way.

**Edit**: if the dates are not ordered, you can order them and save to a vector:

```
dates <- unique(sort(sumc$Date))
sumc$Date <- factor(sumc$Date, labels = dates,  ordered = T)
```

Comment: All factors have an order, the only reason to specify the `ordered factor` class is for the contrasts that are used when it is put in to a model. For dates, the `Date` class is much more appropriate than a `factor` class anyway.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm sometimes a little reluctant to use the `Date` class because it can get messy if the input is using some non-standard date format, but you're right about that.

Comment: Well, your sorting will just go in alphabetical order (unless it's a `Date` class), which is exactly the problem that OP already has.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I am so grateful for this!

Answer (score 4):

Convert to a `Date` class:

```
sumc$Date = as.Date(sumc$Date, format = "%m/%d%/Y")
```

Then your same plotting code will work just fine.

See `?as.Date` or `strptime` for details about the conversion or the `format` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Another way if your dates are imported in the correct order is to use

```
sumc$Date <- factor(sumc$Date, levels = unique(sumc$Date))
```

before plotting.