# How to plot into month-year order instead of alphabetic order in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to plot a frequency plot due to month and year

However my problem is that the x-axis is order due to alphabetic order and not according to month and year (December 2018, January 2019, February 2019 etc.)

I tried to convert the month column as.Date but it makes all values null. How can I make it?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
theme_set(theme_pubr())
monthplot = data.frame(month = c("December 2018", "January 2019", "February 2019", "March 2019", "April 2019", "May 2019", "June 2019", "July 2019"), visits = c(96267, 59939, 48340, 56886, 37785, 56245, 38328, 25284))
#monthplot$month <- as.Date(monthplot$month, format = "%m %Y")

ggplot(monthplot, aes(x = month, y = visits)) +
  geom_bar(fill = "#0073C2FF", stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = visits), vjust = -0.3) + 
  theme_pubclean()
```

Comment: can this help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020146/how-can-i-order-the-months-chronologically-in-ggplot2-short-of-writing-the-month and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38514031/order-of-dates-is-not-chronological-in-ggplot2?

Comment: the `lubridate` package can help converting a character to a date. e.g., `lubridate::dmy("December 2018", truncated = -1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `lubridate` to make a date from the month column

```
monthplot <- monthplot %>% 
  mutate(date = lubridate::dmy(month, truncated = -1))

ggplot(monthplot, aes(x = date, y = visits)) +
  geom_col(fill = "#0073C2FF") +
  geom_text(aes(label = visits), vjust = -0.3) + 
  theme_pubclean()
```

If you want to change how the date is shown, use `scale_x_date` and set the `date_breaks` and/or `date_labels` arguments

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
theme_set(theme_pubr())
monthplot = data.frame(month = c("December 2018", "January 2019", "February 2019", "March 2019", "April 2019", "May 2019", "June 2019", "July 2019"), visits = c(96267, 59939, 48340, 56886, 37785, 56245, 38328, 25284))
#monthplot$month <- as.Date(monthplot$month, format = "%m %Y")


## first add a date field 

monthplot <- 
monthplot %>%  
  mutate(date2 = paste('15', tolower(substr(month, 1, 3)), sep = '-')) %>% 
  mutate(date2 = paste(date2,  gsub('[^0-9]', '', month), sep = '-'))  %>%
  mutate(date2 = as.Date(date2, '%d-%b-%Y')) 

## then reorder your bars by that date field 

ggplot(monthplot, aes(x = reorder(month, date2), y = visits)) +
  geom_bar(fill = "#0073C2FF", stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = visits), vjust = -0.3) + 
  theme_pubclean() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle  = 60, hjust = 1))
```